# How can a web server installed on the same host as the FTP server?

Tags: web-server, ftp, http

I have a situation here where I have to make ftp to be available like http://ftp.example.com instead of ftp.example.com. Somebody advised me to install a web server on the same host as FTP server. Also I need to turn on the directory browsing in web browser.

Currently I am using shared hosting in godaddy. Here I am not allowed to install web server or the ftp server. How can I make my ftp to accessed like http://ftp.example.com. Is there any way I can do by altering .htaccess file?

Please guide me
Regards

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The URL `http://ftp.example.com` is an HTTP URL as it starts with `http`. You just need to define the subdomain `ftp.example.com` to point to your web server and configure your web server accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have ftp available as http://ftp.example.com
You can use http://ftp.example.com and let people browse around and download files but that is just a web site with directory browsing allowed. It is not ftp.

To use ftp you need to have an ftp-server which can happily coexist on the same machine as you r web server as they both listen to different ports.

I don't know anything about godaddy, but I doubt they give you your own a public ftp server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to allow file listing you can add "Options +Indexes" to your .htaccess file and this would allow content to be listed.  If you are trying to allow visitors to upload content to your site you will not be able to do this as Go Daddy does not allow anonymous FTP access.  The safest option for user submitted content to be added to your site would be to use a CMS of some sort; however, you can also script a page that would allow direct uploads via PHP.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the others the URL you've listed is for http traffic only if you want to access FTP over a browser you need to use the URL of ftp://ftp.server.com, this tells the browser to use the ftp protocol to connect but anyone accessing this will need the logins for ftp as most hosting companies will not allow anonymous ftp logins.

If you don't want to play around with a CMS have a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) for info on creating a script to allow file uploads through PHP.